# What happens in onSugggestionClick

Tags: android

I have tried to understand the following code ,I know that this switches from one screen to another.
I have read about `getSuggestionAdapter()`in the developer website,
But I don't entirely understand what they mean.It says on the website that it "returns the adapter used for suggestions".
Does this means it returns the details about the item?
Also I read about `intent.putExtra` and its says that it "adds extended data to intent" .What data could that be?Thank you.

```
@Override
    public boolean onSuggestionClick(int position) {
        int id = (int) searchView.getSuggestionsAdapter().
                getItemId(position);

        Intent intent = new Intent(this, ProSearchActivity.class);

        intent.putExtra("id", id);

        startActivity(intent);

        return true;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It just gives the data associated with the click position, letting you handle and use it in whichever way you like

Comment: Oh ok so ,lets say an item was clicked at position 3 and it returns then the details about that item for e.g like Name:apple ,Quantity:5 and Category :Fruit . Do I have the right idea ?

Comment: Yeah bro, it returns the object of the corresponding type from which you could get the values you wish to extract

Comment: As i  can see you get an id, and using the id you could extract the adapter's corresponding object and for custom models used, cast them to your model class and extract the values